# Why Is Eclipse Indexing the Wrong Value Of a Nonexistent Preprocessor Macro?

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded

I'm using an old m68k-elf-gcc that doesn't support C99 on a project, with Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 as my IDE.  One of my cross-project header files has the following code which tests for C99, and if C99 is found, uses stdint.h, or if not, manually defines some of the fixed size `_t` types:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L /* C99, with support for stdint.h>. */
#include <stdint.h>
#else
/* Make sure to set these up correctly for your system if you don't have stdint.h. */
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef short int16_t;
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
#endif
```

This compiles fine, and uses the lower section where stuff is manually set up.  Eclipse's indexer, however, insists that `__STDC_VERSION__` exists, and in fact has the exact value `199901L` (that value shows up when hovering the cursor over the macro name).  This causes the Eclipse text editor and "Problems" tab to show errors on any line that uses the `_t` types, even though those lines compile fine.

I know it's easy enough to work around this particular problem - erase everything but the manual typedefs from my header file - but I would really prefer that the Eclipse indexer have some relation to the compiler version I'm using.  I have set the following project properties to make Eclipse aware that I'm using a different GCC:

- "C/C++ Build"->"Discovery Options:" Set the compiler invocation command to "m68k-elf-gcc"
- "C/C++ Build"->"Tool Chain Editor:" Set the "Current toolchain" to "Cross GCC"

These seem to have at least some of the desired effect, because the indexer references the correct system includes (goes to the m68k-elf-gcc include directories when perusing headers, not the "vanilla" GCC's include directories), and the "Includes" and "Symbols" tabs on the "C/C++ General"->"Paths and Symbols" properties screen all match the m68k-elf-gcc stuff (and no, `__STDC_VERSION__` is not listed in the Symbols list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual value of `__STDC_VERSION__` used by your compiler is invisible to Eclipse as it is a pre-defined macro rather than being defined in any header file.  Eclipse must therefore be getting this value from somewhere else.  I believe that it is defined [internally within the CDT parser](http://eclipse-cdt.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.1.2-2/classorg_1_1eclipse_1_1cdt_1_1internal_1_1core_1_1parser_1_1scanner2_1_1BaseScanner-members.html).